# Read and write to/from SQL databases with Apache Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, jdbc

I would like to understand why when working with Apache Spark we don't explicitly close JDBC connections.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector
or https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Is this due to the fact, that when we do

```
val collection = sqlContext.read.sqlDB(config)
```

or

```
jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
   (...)
  .save()
```

we don't really open the connection but merely specify a DAG stage? And then under the hood Spark establishes the connection and closes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, Spark takes care of opening/closing JDBC connections to relational data sources during plan execution phase. This allows it to maintain level of abstraction required to support a multitude of various `DataSource` types. You can check the source code of [`JdbcRelationProvider`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcRelationProvider.scala#L48) (for read) or [`JdbcUtils`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L628) (for save) to review that logic.